# Variable stack size on stack overflow exception

Tags: .net, security, aslr

I have a top-level console app targeting net5 with this code:

```cs
Work();
void Work()
{
    Work();
}
```

It will eventually throw a `StackOverflowException` and print to the console the last known stack size. Here are the results of a few runs:

```
32120
32113
32133
32127
```

I also see this variability of the stack size when I target .net framework 4.8.

I looked at [ECMA-335 Standard: Common Language Infrastructure](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) and found this sentence, regarding `StackOverflowException`: *"The precise timing of this exception and the conditions under which it occurs are implementation-specific"*.
Then I found out about ASLR (address space layout randomization), and thought that perhaps the CLI implementation uses a similar technique.

My question is, **why does this variability exist and if ASLR is turned off, how could a potential attack work?**

Comment: I always thought ASLR randomized the base address of stack/heaps/..., not their size, so ASLR shouldn't changed the maximum recursion depth of a program... But I'm not truly expert of the inner working of the .NET runtime

Answer (score 0):

ASLR may limit the size of the stack if there is not enough space in that location for the stack to expand.

Do not assume anything about timing of `StackOverflowException`. Anytime you have a risk of hitting it due to deep recursion, you should use a custom `Stack` object on the heap and convert your code to the iterative form.